# Navigate to another screen with react-native-navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Good afternoon everyone. I'm a little bit stucked with a navigation on button click.

I would like to move to another screen on a button click

Button code part **(./Components/Dashboard.js):**

```
<List>
  <ListItem avatar>
    <Left>
      <Thumbnail source={{ uri: 'image-url' }} />
    </Left>
    <Body>
      <Button dark transparent>
        <Text>Euro</Text>
        <Text>4200</Text>
      </Button>
    </Body>
  </ListItem>
</List>
```

And I have a new screen with few buttons **(./Components/Screens/EuroScreen.js)**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Button, View, Text } from 'react-native';
function HomeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Euro Screen</Text>
      <Button dark>Test</Button>
    </View>
  );
}
```

How I can add a `click` property to my `Button` in `./Components/Dashboard`?

Answer (score 0):

This might help

```
Dashboard({ navigation }) {
    return (
      <View>
        <List>
          <ListItem avatar>
            <Left>
              <Thumbnail source={{ uri: "image-url" }} />
            </Left>
            <Body>
              <Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate("EuroScreen")}>
                <Text>Euro</Text>
                <Text>4200</Text>
              </Button>
            </Body>
          </ListItem>
        </List>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I receive that ' can't find variable navigate' even that I import a 'NavigationContainer' from  react-navigate

Comment: You can access navigation object by "this.props.navigation.navigate('EuroScreen')" React Navigation https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigating